# How to pass directives to an element in the directives template in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directive called `step-field`, in the template of the directive i have input or select elements that should sometimes have max-length or ng-required or some custom directive like `validate-username`.

The step field looks like this:

```
<step-field parent="Admin" field="Username"></step-field>
```

I want to add "validate-username" and "required=true" to this directive so it will look like this

```
<step-field parent="Admin" field="Username" validate-username required="true"></step-field>
```

And in the inside of the directive template i want the validate-username and required to be passed to the input field.
(btw $scope.isRequired = attrs.required)

```
<div class="field">
    <label> {{fieldName}}:</label>
    <input
            name="{{inputName}}"
            ng-model="wizard[modelName][fieldNameCamel]"
            ng-required="{{isRequired}}"
            type="{{inputType}}"/>
    <div class="field--required" ng-if="isRequired===true"> * </div>
    <div class="ng-messages__wrap"
         ng-show="wizardForm[step][inputName].$dirty || wizardSubmittedOnce">
        <div ng-messages="wizardForm[step][inputName].$error"
             ng-messages-include="/templates/error-messages.html"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i apply some of the directives i pass to step-field to the input field in the template?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you did apply (at least, you did with `{{isRequired}}`). Did it not work?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'd really like to know.